# XMPP doesn't disconnect properly while terminate the application?

Tags: ios, iphone, xmpp

XMPP doesn't disconnect properly while terminate the application?

B'cas i need to enable APNS once application is terminated by user same as whatsapp work.

If i close app within 2 min while connecting with XMPP server, than APNS enable quickly. But if i close application after 5-6 min than APNS doesn't enable quickly. It may take 1-2 min or some time more. In case of 5-6 min, if i lock device than APNS is enable quickly.

I have use below code for push configuration and disconnect the XMPP.

```
-(void)configurePushNotifications
{
    NSString *jabberID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"test123"];

    NSXMLElement *iq = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"iq"];
    [iq addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"set"];
    [iq addAttributeWithName:@"id" stringValue:strDeviceToken];

    NSXMLElement *push = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"push" xmlns:@"p1:push"];

    NSXMLElement *ping = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"ping" xmlns:@"urn:xmpp:ping"];

    NSXMLElement *keepalive = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"keepalive"];
    [keepalive addAttributeWithName:@"max" integerValue:60];

    NSXMLElement *session = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"session"];
    [session addAttributeWithName:@"duration" integerValue:60];

    NSXMLElement *body = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"body"];
    [body addAttributeWithName:@"send" stringValue:@"all"];
    [body addAttributeWithName:@"groupchat" stringValue:@"true"];
    [body addAttributeWithName:@"from" stringValue:@"username"];

    NSXMLElement *status = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"status"];
    [status addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"xa"];
    [status setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"New message from %@",jabberID]];

    NSXMLElement *offline = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"offline" stringValue:@"true"];

    [push addChild:keepalive];
    [push addChild:session];
    [push addChild:body];
    [push addChild:status];
    [push addChild:offline];

    NSXMLElement *notification = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"notification"];
    [notification addChild:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"applepush"]];
    [notification addChild:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"id" stringValue:strDeviceToken]];

    [push addChild:notification];

    NSXMLElement *appid = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"appid" stringValue:@"com.test.test"];

    [push addChild:appid];

    [iq addChild:ping];
    [iq addChild:push];
    [[self xmppStream] sendElement:iq];
}

- (void)goOffline
{
    XMPPPresence *presence = [XMPPPresence presenceWithType:@"unavailable"];

    [[self xmppStream] sendElement:presence];
}

- (void)goOnline
{
    XMPPPresence *presence = [XMPPPresence presence]; // type="available" is implicit

    NSString *domain = [xmppStream.myJID domain];

    //Google set their presence priority to 24, so we do the same to be compatible.

    if([domain isEqualToString:@"gmail.com"]
       || [domain isEqualToString:@"gtalk.com"]
       || [domain isEqualToString:@"talk.google.com"])
    {
        NSXMLElement *priority = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"priority" stringValue:@"24"];
        [presence addChild:priority];
    }

    [[self xmppStream] sendElement:presence];
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.

    [self goOffline];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [self goOnline];
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: i think when you terminate your app, than XMPP automatically disconnect from your xmpp server...

Comment: If XMPP automatically disconnect from XMPP server than i am able to get push from APNS. But in some case its not going to disconnect or it may take longer to disconnect the XMPP. 
As per my knowledge, XMPP enable push service after socket close successfully.

Comment: I have updated the question.Please check that. 
So, to enable APNS push (in case if i close app after 5-6 min than), i have to wait until device screen is lock.

Comment: @iPhoneDev any suggestion here !!

Comment: @NiravPatel I am facing same issue. Is there any solution you found ?